# create unique and editable profiles

Tags: wordpress, user-accounts

I am working on a web development project that will require keeping records for around 3-4,000  companies. If possible I want to use a wordpress plugin that enables a user to CREATE a unique user account / profile and update their profile with their up to date information at a later date. I tested profile builder but it wont let non admins initiate a new account (something I dont want to do 4,000 times).

Information also needs to be searchable (income range, location, etc.). This is not necessarily a deal breaker as I could develop a second app to search the DB.

Right now I am trying to choose between building a app where a user can create an account and interact with a UI (time consuming). I hate to ask such silly question but I am not having much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Approximate wireframe:

- Enable user registration and dispatch the 4 thousand emails inviting to open an account.
- The default User Profile system remains as it is, just basic user info (it's easy to remove stuff from that page and give it a nice style).
- Create a Custom Post Type for the *big profile* with all the searchable capabilities this offers.
- [Limit the number of posts the user can manage to One](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/36416/12615).
- [Ask new questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as the specifics arise.